# Android unlocking pattern

Tags: android, design-patterns, locking

i wanted to know is there any way to find what pattern was made in the pattern unlock of android.

i mean i want to know what pattern has been made by the user while trying to unlock the phone.

there are broadcast receivers that inform u when the phone is unlocked..... but i want to know whether there is any way i know the pattern every time user tries to unlock correctly or falsely.

Are there any receivers that inform the application at every unlocking pattern?

Thank you..

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully, this isn't possible - it would represent a significant security flaw. Imagine logging the passcode used to unlock an iDevice...

Frankly, I can't see any beneficial use of such a function either. I'd have expected that such things were strictly used for malicious purposes. Why would you be interested in such data?

Comment: let me be clear first of all i have no malicious ideas. i dont even want to know the correct unlocking pattern. I want to have a secondary locking pattern that could symbolise an emergency sort of situation

Comment: I'm afraid that you'll need to look for another implementation.

Comment: ya i suppose so...may be a new home screen implementation... any help in that?